# properly discontinuous actions of every countable group

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a group, acting with homeomorphisms on a space $X$. The action is called a properly discontinuous action if for every $x\in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ such that for all $g\in G, g\ne1$ we have $(g.U)\cap U = \emptyset$.

My question is, can every countable group act properly discontinuous on $\Bbb R^2$?
I think that there is something to do with the rank of the group, and I think that it is impossible for $\Bbb Z^3$, but I can't prove.

Comment: I suspect there is an easier proof, but do you know about the classification of surfaces?  A properly discontinuous action gives a covering map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^3$, so the quotient space has $\pi_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$.  From the classification, non-compact surfaces always have free $\pi_1$, and for closed surfaces, you can get $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but not $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: One can prove that $\mathbb Z^3$ is not the fundamental group of a surface without the full power of the classification of closed surfaces, but you do have to use *something* about the topology of surfaces, e.g. Poincaré Duality (with $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ coefficients).